# NameNotFoundException in weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi

I have a web application that has been written in java.When I run my webLogic server, the server is running. But when I send a SOAP request it gives Unable to resolve 'xxx-yyyy-zzz-JNDI'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'xxx-yyyy-zzz-JNDI'.

I tested my jndi configuration, it is working(pass and username are correct).I realized there is no deployed instance of this data source in monitoring tab on weblogic. I think problem is here. Do you have any idea?

MY error code : `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'efaturaQdbDataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-efatura-data.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'xxx-yyyy-zzz-JNDI'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'xxx-yyyy-zzz-JNDI' at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322) ... 98 more Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'xxx-yyyy-zzz-JNDI'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'xxx-yyyy-zzz-JNDI' at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1139) at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookupHere(BasicNamingNode.java:252) at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookupHere(ServerNamingNode.java:182) at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:206) at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:254) at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:393) at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392) at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154) at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87) at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152) at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178) at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95) at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105) at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201) at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ... 105 more`

Comment: Kindly paste the whole stack trace. Furthermore, you should check the JNDI tree on Weblogic console. Include your code, specially the section, which is failing.

Comment: I checked jndi tree and i saw my jndi is not there.How can I add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for sharing the whole stack trace, now the problem is more understandable.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
with name 'efaturaQdbDataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext- 
 efatura-data.xml]
```

I think you are facing issues with the data source called efaturaQdbDataSource. Therefore, you should create the data source first following this [guide](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/04-ConfigDataSource/configds.htm). After following these steps you will see the data source within the JNDI tree.

In my experience this is the best way to manage a data source instead of including it as part of your application why? because you will split the configuration of the data source and its administration from your application, which is useful when your application is in production.